# Java: Standing Animation

Tags: java, rpg, tilemap, logic

I've been working on a top-down, and the player already has animations for moving left and right.  However, if I move a certain distance and stop, it will stop on the walking animation, which isn't logical as opposed to a standing animation while the player is idle.

I've been using this input handler class:

```
public class InputHandler implements KeyListener
{       
public boolean up = false;
public boolean down = false;
public boolean left = false;
public boolean right = false;

public InputHandler(Game game)
{
    game.addKeyListener(this);
}

public void toggle(KeyEvent ke, boolean Pressed)
{
    int KeyCode = ke.getKeyCode();

    if(KeyCode == ke.VK_UP) up = Pressed;
    if(KeyCode == ke.VK_DOWN) down = Pressed;
    if(KeyCode == ke.VK_LEFT) left = Pressed;
    if(KeyCode == ke.VK_RIGHT) right = Pressed;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    toggle(e, true);
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
    toggle(e, false);
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
{

}
}
```

and it is coupled with the tick() method from my main class:

```
private void tick()
{
    if(input.right)
    {
        xScroll++;

        if(xScroll / 16 % 2 == 0)
        {
            dirFacing = 2;
        }
        if(xScroll / 16 % 2 != 0)
        {
            dirFacing = 4;
        }
    }

    if(input.left)
    {
        xScroll--;

        if(xScroll / 16 % 2 == 0)
        {
            dirFacing = 1;
        }
        if(xScroll / 16 % 2 != 0)
        {
            dirFacing = 3;
        }
    }

    if(input.down)
    {
        yScroll++;
    }

    if(input.up)
    {
        yScroll--;
    }
}
```

Again, the above yScroll will be added later, I really just need to solve the standing animation first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve this is to add a check to see if none of direction flags are set. Then use that case to start the idle animation in the `tick()`.

For instance:

`if(!input.up && !input.down && !input.right && !input.left) 
{
    //play idle animation this frame
}`

Another thing to consider is the direction of the idle animation. If your character is walking left, and the idle animation shows them looking down, when the player stops moving the character will suddenly change directions. This can be solved with having 4 different idle animations. Then you use the `dirFacing` from your last tick to determine which one to play.

One last point is you aren't checking the time between ticks anywhere. If you store the delta time between ticks you can make the animation play at the same rate no matter how fast or slow the `tick()` method gets called

Comment: Yeah I've really tried to skimp out on timed things since i don't want to have to deal with threads (I'm still kind of a beginner) although I probably will have to add them at some point even though it's just a Pokemon mock up.  Thanks for the help though the !input.____ worked!

Comment: @A.K. I wonder how you came to the conclusion to use threads? Using delta-time has nothing to do with threads... you don't have to deal with multiple threads for that.

Comment: I was thinking the timing needed like the pause(500milliseconds) method or that threads were needed for measuring the time?

Comment: The way I usually see it done is with a while loop. The while loop first checks from any input from the OS and increases a time counter every loop. Then, when the time counter goes over a minimum amount, it calls the tick() with a deltaTime in milliseconds.

Comment: So there is a pause before initiating movement via the tick() inputs?  I can't find a great place to put the while(input != null) without it giving me a blank screen because the rest of my code didn't fire.

Comment: You could put the code to check the time since last update in your tick() if you want. Just store a global variable: long lastUpdateMS. Then initialize it to be: lastUpdateMS = System.nanoTime() / 1000000. Then every tick() check it to see if it has been long enough ago like: int deltaMS = (System.nanoTime() / 1000000) - lastUpdate; Lastly, you want to see how many times per second to run the logic. deltaMS is the time in milliseconds since the last time you updated. if you want to check 60 times per second, use if(deltaMS > 16). Then inside the logic set lastUpdate += deltaMS;

Comment: Alright that seemed to break your explanation down easier.  I just have to tweak the numbers and my character should be all set. Thanks.